# how to insert into set without changing the equals and hashcode

Tags: java, groovy, set, guava, hashset

I'm looking for a suggestion.
I have a `Person` class with String firstName and String lastName
When  i'm tying to insert the list values with the same String like :

```
set.add(new Person("firstName","lastName"))

set.add(new Person("firstName","lastName"))
```

The set doesn`t filter the objects and they still getting in the set.
There is any suggestion to create set list without overriding the equales and hashcode functions?
Maybe with guava or some groovy list?
Thanks,
Or.

Comment: What's the problem with overriding `equals` and `hashCode`?

Comment: My class is more complicated than the Person example.
I am using groovy and i have a groovy class with 2 domains and more variables so i don't want to change my equal, i just need one time to create some Set that depends only in 2 Strings of my class.

Comment: If the code you provide is executed what do you want the result to be? Two persons in the set? The first person only in the set? Normally the result would be that just the second person remains in the set.

Comment: @ork In the end, you'll probably be much better off doing it the correct way, and getting `equals` and `hashcode` right...  People are going to fall over this further down the line, assuming they are correctly implemented, not that you used a TreeSet with a custom comparator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#TreeSet%28java.util.Comparator%29) with your own Comparator.

```
Set<Person> set = new TreeSet<Person>(new Comparator<Person>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
        // Your own compare logic
    }
});
```

Comment: A clever, but probably not a good idea. Implement `equals()` and `hashcode()`, if you have to implement some method anyway. Just using `TreeSet`, when the functionality provided in not needed actually, is another bad idea.

Comment: @AdeelAnsari It all depends on the context. If it suits his needs then I can't really see the problem.

Comment: Me neither, it seems to be a good fit for the problem. If you want a solution that solves the problem and makes "correct" use of collections then you could use a map, keyed with a new class that holds just the firstname and lastname fields.

Comment: @GlenLamb: From the docs "Note that the ordering maintained by a set (whether or not an explicit comparator is provided) must be consistent with equals if it is to correctly implement the Set interface."

Comment: That's interesting, why would you want a comparator that overrides the equals functionality if it's supposed to be consistent with equals?

Comment: @AdeelAnsari This is from the same docs: "The behavior of a set is well-defined even if its ordering *is* inconsistent with equals; it just fails to obey the general contract of the Set interface"

Comment: The OP says in his comments: *i just need one time to create some Set that depends only in 2 Strings of my class*. I cannot see how using a TreeSet with a comparator would be a problem.

Comment: @maba: Indeed, that's why you didn't get a downvote. Because it's valid, but not a good practice to not fulfil the general contract. And that was exactly my point.

Comment: @AdeelAnsari OK, fair enough. I agree on what you say. My answer is just a way for him to solve his actual problem.

Comment: @ork BTW, you'd better read this [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) so you know how to accept answers.

Answer (score 12):

In Guava there's an [Equivalence](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Equivalence.html) class designed to such things. Create your own `Equivalence` class like this one:

```
import com.google.common.base.Equivalence;
import com.google.common.base.Objects;

public class PersonEquivalence extends Equivalence<Person> {

  @Override
  protected boolean doEquivalent(Person p1, Person p2) {
    return Objects.equal(p1.getFistName(), p2.getFistName())
        && Objects.equal(p1.getLastName(), p2.getLastName());
  }

  @Override
  protected int doHash(Person person) {
    return Objects.hashCode(person.getFistName(), person.getLastName());
  }

}
```

And then this code

```
Set<Equivalence.Wrapper<Person>> set = Sets.newHashSet();
PersonEquivalence personEquivalence = new PersonEquivalence();
set.add(personEquivalence.wrap(new Person("Joe", "Doe")));
set.add(personEquivalence.wrap(new Person("Joe", "Doe")));
set.add(personEquivalence.wrap(new Person("Jane", "Doe")));
System.out.println(set);
```

prints

```
[PersonEquivalence@8813f2.wrap(Person{firstName=Jane, lastName=Doe}),
 PersonEquivalence@8813f2.wrap(Person{firstName=Joe, lastName=Doe})]
```

Of course it's a bit verbose, but you can create [ForwardingSet](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ForwardingSet.html) to automatically wrap and unwrap `Person`s for you.

Answer (score 4):

You can't, without violating the contract of `Set`. Either don't use a `Set`, or wrap the `Person` in another class that implements `equals` and `hashcode` based on the inner `Person` (see the other answer for a way to do this in Guava).

Comment: Better say, "you shouldn't", instead of "you can't". +1

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rough attempt at my map suggestion.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

public class PeopleCarrier implements Iterable<Person>{

    private Map<PersonKey, Person> storage = new HashMap<PersonKey, Person>();

    public void add(Person p) {
        PersonKey pk = new PersonKey(p);
        storage.put(pk, p);     
    }

    public boolean contains(Person p) {
        return storage.containsKey(new PersonKey(p));
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Person> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<Person>() {

            private Iterator<PersonKey> i = storage.keySet().iterator();

            @Override
            public void remove() {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }

            @Override
            public Person next() {
                return storage.get(i.next());               
            }

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return i.hasNext();
            }
        };
    }

    private class PersonKey {
        private String firstname;
        private String lastname;
        public PersonKey(Person p) {
            this.firstname = p.getFirstname();
            this.lastname = p.getLastname();
        }
        /* (non-Javadoc)
         * @see java.lang.Object#hashCode()
         */
        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + getOuterType().hashCode();
            result = prime * result
                    + ((firstname == null) ? 0 : firstname.hashCode());
            result = prime * result
                    + ((lastname == null) ? 0 : lastname.hashCode());
            return result;
        }
        /* (non-Javadoc)
         * @see java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)
         */
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (!(obj instanceof PersonKey))
                return false;
            PersonKey other = (PersonKey) obj;
            if (!getOuterType().equals(other.getOuterType()))
                return false;
            if (firstname == null) {
                if (other.firstname != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!firstname.equals(other.firstname))
                return false;
            if (lastname == null) {
                if (other.lastname != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!lastname.equals(other.lastname))
                return false;
            return true;
        }
        private PeopleCarrier getOuterType() {
            return PeopleCarrier.this;
        }   

    }
}
```