# Customizing the get method in HashMap

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Case insensitive string as HashMap key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236945/case-insensitive-string-as-hashmap-key)

I have a Hashmap with a String as the key and an integer as the value. Now, I am using the get method to get the values, where the string matches with the key value.

---

```
HashMap<String,Integer> map= new HashMap<String,Integer>();
// Populate the map

System.out.println(map.get("mystring"));
```

---

I want this string comparison to be case insensitive. Is there anyway I can do that ?

---

For example, I want it to return the same result in the following cases:

---

```
map.get("hello");
map.get("HELLO");
map.get("Hello");
```

Comment: may be do .toLowercase() while doing lookup?

Answer (score 3):

If performance is not critical, you can use a [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html). Output of the code below:

> 1
>   6
>   6

Note that the behaviour you require is not compliant with [`Map#get` contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29):

> More formally, if this map contains a mapping from a key k to a value v such that (key==null ? k==null : key.equals(k)), then this method returns v; otherwise it returns null. (There can be at most one such mapping.)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);

    map.put("hello", 3);
    map.put("HELLO", 6);
    System.out.println(map.size());
    System.out.println(map.get("heLLO"));
    System.out.println(map.get("hello"));
}
```

Comment: +1 Using a custom comparator is cleaner than sub classing.

Comment: That will not work. The comparator is not consistent with `equals()`, which, according to [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html), is a requirement for a `TreeMap` to correctly implement the `Map` interface.

Comment: @TedHopp The behaviour required by the OP is not consistent with `String#equals`. So I don't see how you can implement it in a way that complies with Map's contract (including using the subclassing / wrapper options proposed in other answers).

Comment: @TedHopp Added a comment to clarify.

Comment: Good point -- OP's requirement technically isn't for a `Map` (according to Java's definition of a `Map`).

Comment: @assylias Watch out for the police squad! I had a similar [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12508332/how-to-insert-into-set-without-changing-the-equals-and-hashcode/12508664#12508664) that was frowned upon. +1 on this one from me!

Comment: @TedHopp: "The behavior of a sorted map is well-defined even if its ordering is inconsistent with equals; it just fails to obey the general contract of the Map interface."  This would be my solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
Map<String,Integer> map= new HashMap<String,Integer>() {
    @Override
    public Integer put(String key, Integer value) {
      return super.put(key.toLowerCase(), value);
    }

    @Override
    public Integer get(Object o) {
       return super.get(o.toString().toLowerCase());
    }
};
```

Comment: You also need to override `put` to lower-case all keys. Otherwise you can never retrieve values stored under keys that are not already lower case. You probably also have to deal with `putAll` and the constructor that takes another map as an argument.

Comment: I get that you are doing a lookup for the tolowercase of the query string, but what if the lower case version was never inserted?

Comment: Added put but not `contains` and a few others you might need.

Comment: A wrapper class is probably a better approach than subclassing. It's an easier way to deal with those "others".

Answer (score 1):

You can create a wrapper class that will wrap the HashMap and implement the get and put methods.

Answer (score 1):

```
HashMap<InsensitiveString,Integer> map= new HashMap<>();

map.get(new InsensitiveString("mystring"));

---

public class InsensitiveString

    final String string;

    public InsensitiveString(String string)
        this.string = string;

    public int hashCode()
        calculate hash code based on lower case of chars in string

    public boolean equals(Object that)
        compare 2 strings insensitively
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a wrapper method which will put `String` like below a

```
map.put(string.toLowerCase());
```

and get method

```
map.get(string.toLowerCase());
```