# Consequence when compareTo() is inconsistent with equals()

Tags: java

Can somebody put some light on what are the Consequences when `compareTo()` is inconsistent with `equals()` of a class. I have read that if `Obj1.compareTo(Obj2) = 0` then it's not mandatory to be `Obj1.equals(Obj2) = true`. But what is the consequence if this happens. Thanks.

Comment: not unless you make one

Comment: @Sam I am can you be please more elaborative.

Comment: The question is very vague. The consequence is "if you compare them in two different ways, you get two different answers" - the *follow-on* consequence depends on why you're performing that comparison.

Comment: for instance, i fyou typed a line like `if (Obj1.equals(Obj2) && Obj1.compareTo(Obj2)!= 0){throw new exception();}`  then them being inconsistant would throw exceptions

Comment: These issues i ran into a lot when had to implement a comparator. Equals did one thing but comparator absolutely another (i used it for sorting). One has to be carefull not to loose elements when implementing comparable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparator best practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12724051/comparator-best-practice)

Comment: [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#compareTo(java.math.BigDecimal)) is an example where it's not consistent.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The documentation for [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) explains this in some detail:

> The natural ordering for a class `C` is said to be consistent with `equals` if and only if `e1.compareTo(e2) == 0` has the same boolean value as `e1.equals(e2)` for every `e1` and `e2` of class `C`. Note that `null` is not an instance of any class, and `e.compareTo(null)` should throw a `NullPointerException` even though `e.equals(null)` returns `false`.
>
> It is strongly recommended (though not required) that natural orderings be consistent with `equals`. This is so because sorted sets (and sorted maps) without explicit comparators behave "strangely" when they are used with elements (or keys) whose natural ordering is inconsistent with `equals`. In particular, such a sorted set (or sorted map) violates the general contract for set (or map), which is defined in terms of the `equals` method.
>
> For example, if one adds two keys `a` and `b` such that `(!a.equals(b) && a.compareTo(b) == 0)` to a sorted set that does not use an explicit comparator, the second add operation returns `false` (and the size of the sorted set does not increase) because `a` and `b` are equivalent from the sorted set's perspective.
>
> Virtually all Java core classes that implement `Comparable` have natural orderings that are consistent with `equals`. One exception is `java.math.BigDecimal`, whose natural ordering equates `BigDecimal` objects with equal values and different precisions (such as `4.0` and `4.00`).

Comment: Example where it is useful to have `compareTo` inconsistent with `equals`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12587896/customizing-the-get-method-in-hashmap/12588005#12588005

Comment: @NPE Can you please explain a bit this "In particular, such a sorted set (or sorted map) violates the general contract for set (or map), which is defined in terms of the equals method." with an example. I am not able to get it properly. thanks.

Comment: @Trying: From the docs for `Set`: *sets contain no pair of elements e1 and e2 such that e1.equals(e2)*. On the other hand, a `SortedSet` (which must fulfil this contract because it is-a `Set`) uses `compareTo()` instead of `equals()`. Thus if your objects don't implement `compareTo/equals` consistently, and you put them in a `SortedSet`, you'll force the latter to break its contract.

Answer (score 3):

Although the documentation says that consistency is not mandatory, it is better to always ensure this consistency, as you never know whether your object may be one day present in a `TreeMap` / `TreeSet` or the like. If `compareTo()` returns 0 for 2 objects that are not equal, then all Tree based collections are broken.

For example, imagine a class `Query`, implementing an SQL query, with 2 fields:

- tableList: list of tables
- references: list of programs using such a query

Let's say that 2 objects are equal if their tableList is equal, i.e. the `tableList` is the natural key of this object. `hashCode()` and `equals()` only consider the field `tableList`:

```
public class Query implements Comparable {
    List<String> tableList;
    List<String> references;

    Query(List<String> tableList, List<String> references) {
        this.tableList = tableList;
        this.references = references;
        Collections.sort(tableList); // normalize
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 5;
        hash = 53 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.tableList);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Query other = (Query) obj;
        return Objects.equals(this.tableList, other.tableList);
    }
}
```

Let's say that we would like the sorting to be along the number of references.
Writing the code naively yields a `compareTo()` methods which could look like this:

```
public int compareTo(Object o) {
    Query other = (Query) o;
    int s1 = references.size();
    int s2 = other.references.size();
    if (s1 == s2) {
        return 0;
    }
    return s1 - s2;
}
```

Doing so seems OK as equality and sorting are done on two separate fields, so far so good.

However, whenever is put in a `TreeSet` or a `TreeMap`, it is catastrophic: the implementation of these classes consider that if compareTo returns 0, then the elements are equal. In this case, it would mean that each object with identical  number of references are indeed 'equal' objects, which is obviously not the case.

A better `compareTo()` method could be:

```
public int compareTo(Object o) {
    Query other = (Query) o;
    // important to match equals!!!
    if (this.equals(other)) {
        return 0;
    }
    int s1 = references.size();
    int s2 = other.references.size();
    if (s1 == s2) {
        return -1; // not 0, they are NOT equal!
    }
    return s1 - s2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some collections will assume that if two objects follow `obj1.compareTo(obj2) = 0` then `obj1.equals(obj2)` is also true. For example: sorted `TreeSet`.
Failing to meet this logic will result in an iconsistent collection. See:
[Comparator and equals()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344246/comparator-and-equals).