# compareTo error Comparison method violates its general contract

Tags: java, comparable

I get the following error:

> Comparison method violates its general contract!

This is my compareTo method

```
public int compareTo(ComparableItem another) {
     if (this.score == another.score)
        return this.getItemName().compareTo(another.getItemName());
     else if ((this.score) > another.score)
        return 1;
     else
        return -1;
}
```

I want to compare the scores of the items. But when the scores are the same I want to sort them by name.

What do I need to change and why do I get this error?

EDIT:

score is an `int`, itemname a `String`.

This is the ComparableItem class:

```
public abstract class ComparableItem extends MenuListItem implements Comparable<ComparableItem> {

protected int score;

public ComparableItem(String itemID, String itemName) {
    super(itemID, itemName);
}

public int compareTo(ComparableItem another) {
     if (this.score == another.score)
        return this.getItemName().compareTo(another.getItemName());
     else if ((this.score) > another.score)
        return 1;
     else
        return -1;
}

public abstract boolean found(String criteria);
```

And this is the MenuListItem class :

```
public class MenuListItem {

private String itemID,itemName;

public MenuListItem(String itemID, String itemName){
    setItemID(itemID);
    setItemName(itemName);
}

public String getItemID() {
    return itemID;
}

public void setItemID(String itemID) {
    this.itemID = itemID;
}

public String getItemName() {
    return itemName;
}

public void setItemName(String itemName) {
    this.itemName = itemName;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.itemName;
}
```

Comment: Where do you get that error? What's the stack trace?

Comment: i am not an android expert, but shouldn't the signature of the method be "public int cmopareTo(Object another)"?

Comment: Please show the entire class.

Comment: @gefei: No; `Comparable<T>` is generic.

Comment: score is a integer, itemname a string

Comment: Can you show your equals method? Is compareTo consistent with equals?

Comment: I don't have a equals method.. Do I need one ?

Comment: Well there's no way to answer with the given code. Please at least post the class declaration.

Comment: I notice that your ComparableItem class is mutable. Is there any chance the score and/or itemName field is being modified from a different thread at the same time as the sort is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quote from the Java API of `Comparable<T>`:

> The natural ordering for a class C is said to be consistent with
>   equals if and only if (e1.compareTo((Object)e2) == 0) has the same
>   boolean value as e1.equals((Object)e2) for every e1 and e2 of class C.

And for using compareTo, the api further says:

> It is strongly recommended (though not required) that natural
>   orderings be consistent with equals. This is so because sorted sets
>   (and sorted maps) without explicit comparators behave "strangely" when
>   they are used with elements (or keys) whose natural ordering is
>   inconsistent with equals. In particular, such a sorted set (or sorted
>   map) violates the general contract for set (or map), which is defined
>   in terms of the equals method.

So you should probably override equals to be consistent with your `compareTo()`, because otherwise two different objects e1 and e2 with equal `score` and `getItemName()` will have  `e1.compareTo((Object)e2) == 0)` but not `e1.equals((Object)e2)`.

Comment: It also says *"It is strongly recommended (**though not required**) that natural orderings be consistent with equals."*. But whatever is sending the exception might have a strict reading of that rule.

Comment: There are even [situations where you need a compareTo method that is inconsistent with equals](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12588005/829571). ;-)

Comment: How can I make my equals method consistent with compareTo?

I've tried this :


 @Override
 public boolean equals(Object o) {
  final ComparableItem other = (ComparableItem) o;
  if (this.score == other.score && this.getItemName().equals(other.getItemName()))
   return true;
  else
   return false;
 }

Comment: @just8laze that should suffice to align equals and compareTo

Comment: It is a good idea to make equals and compareTo consistent, but a quick browse of the JDK source seems to indicate that this isn't the problem here. The sort code only appears to pay attention to compareTo and never calls equals.

Comment: @Alex: which source code are you referring to? Some implementations of set and maponly use compareTo but have contracts based on equals. Thus the inconsistency...

Comment: @just8laze: your equals() looks logically correct to me (besides exceptional cases, where you should check the class of `other`, and whether it is `null`).

Comment: @DaveBall http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7-gate/jdk/file/e947a98ea3c1/src/share/classes/java/util/ComparableTimSort.java line 715. This class is called from Arrays.sort(Object[]), and based on Google searches for the error message seems to be the likely source of the exception.